# Get current page URL in href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Currently working on a share button for Vk however having a dynamic site, I need the button to automatically use the correct page URL.

This is the code snippet they offer for a static site, how could I adjust this for multiple pages ?

```
<a href="http://vk.com/share.php?url=http://example.com" target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is by JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("vkShare").href =  'http://vk.com/share.php?url='+document.location.href;
```

```html
<a id="vkShare" target="_blank">Share to VK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current page's URL by using a window object like this: `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

simple
works on all sites

```js
function share(){
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  window.prompt('share us',text);
}
copyToClipboard(window.location.href);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="javascript:share();">share </button>
```

Comment: forgot vk sorry but i dont know why you want vk this may be beter but ya sorry

Answer (score 0):

Using php to get the url, try to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to get the host and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get any query string attached to the url.

```html
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

//$complete_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//To use whether HTTP OR HTTPS
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === "on"){
  $htp = "https";
}else{
  $htp = "http";
}
$complete_url = $htp."//:".$host.$uri;
?>

<a href="<?=$complete_url?>" target="_blank">
```